# Imagem é cortada ao diminuir largura da pagina

Tags: html, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em jsp e servlet  e coloquei uma imagem em uma coluna do bootstrap `<div class="col-11"></div>` então coloquei a imagem no centro da tela usando o`margin-left` .Mas ao diminuir a largura da pagina a imagem corta

Imagem na largura normal da pagina

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem cortada com a largura da pagina diminuída

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-11"><img src="imagens/imagem1.JPG"class="imagem_principal" id="desconto" alt="desconto"></div>

    </div>
   #desconto{
width: 90%;
height: 60px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 70px;

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a classe `col-11` aplica a largura através de uma porcentagem (medida relativa) e você aplicou a margem em pixels (medida absoluta).

Para centralizar corretamente a imagem no centro da tela, primeiro você precisa centralizar a `col-11` utilizando `justify-content-center` na `row`. Depois disso, é necessário centralizar a imagem na div utilizando `text-center`.

```
<div class='row justify-content-center'>
    <div class='col-11 text-center'>
        <img src="imagens/imagem1.JPG"class="imagem_principal" id="desconto" alt="desconto">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado Oeslei era isso mesmo